# How to deploy Python API on heroku ? No module named 'app' error

Tags: python, git, api, heroku

I'm a total beginner with heroku and API's but I needed to execute some python for a mobile app project.
Anyway I watched a ton of tutorial and looked for the doc on heroku website but my problem remains the same :

I push my project using $ git push heroku master but when loading the page where my API should appear I get an application error from heroku which tells to check the logs.

So in the logs I am facing the following error : **<< ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app' >>**

I have this code :

`app.py`

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'hello'
```

---

`Procfile`

`web: gunicorn testdamien.wsgi`

---

`wsgi.py`

```
from app import app 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I don't really know what's the use of the wsgi file, I saw some youtubers not using it and directly putting the app.run() in the app.py.

Also, I tried with the following Procfile :

`web: gunicorn app:app`

don't work either...

Thank you for reading me.

Answer (score 0):

So in your `app.py` your application is not running. Edit the file as below:

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

in your `Procfile` you are specifying your entry-point the format is `web: gunicorn your_module_name:your_application name` In your case it will be:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

Should work fine

Comment: In heroku go to your application settings and check project structure. Both your app and wsgi file should be in same directory including Procfile.

Comment: I have a simple directory which is called Test and inside Test I have created both my heroku app and git repo and I don't have any subdirectory inside Test, I'm just trying to deploy the simplest app but I can't figure out why I encounter this problem and other people don't. I also checked project structure and python is recongnized as buildpack.

Comment: if your Procfile is configured properly this shouldn't happen. try creating the application in a different location. then run `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, configure Procfile and push to heorku after committing.

Comment: I tried someone's template on the internet, he put the app file in a app folder and in Procfile : ```web: gunicorn wsgi:app```
It finally works ! I don't know if it came from the procfile or the app file but I'm happy I can get this working :)

Comment: glad to know. you can follow this article for better understanding: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deploy-python-flask-app-on-heroku/